# Adding a new disk to an exsting partition in linux

Tags: mount, partition, opensuse, hard-disk, yast

I have a sda on my opensuse and want to add a new disk to have more space on it.
After adding the disk I have created a partition lets name it sdb.
Mr sda has 6 partition and I ant to sdb to 6th partition sda.

Any one can help me for this?

Comment: Install `GParted` from your repository, and use the `copy` function on the disk menu.

Comment: You mean making a file system in a partition? Disks are made of partitions, not the other way round....

Comment: The partition won't be called `sdb`. That's the name given to your second disk. If you did create a partition perhaps you mean `sdb1`? Please use specifics here, particularly as you sound like a relative newcomer to Linux-based systems, so that we can give you specific responses. (If you get this sort of thing wrong you can end up erasing your main disk's data.) You may want to [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/218338/edit) to provide the missing specifics.

Comment: Can you edit you question to make it clear. Tell up what you are trying to do, avoid jargon here, just tell us what you want. Then tell us what you have tried, and what happened.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like the logical volume manager, lvm.  Partitions like /dev/sda6 are specific to one disk.  However, using lvm you can create logical volumes that span multiple disks.